# Средставами Winapi при нажатии кнопки искать окно с текстом, не заголовком

Tags: winapi, delphi-7

Суть такова: средставами Winapi при нажатии кнопки искать окно с текстом, не заголовком. Текст может быть как textbox, так и label.

**Обновление**

```
if (wnd <> Application.Handle)//собственное
and IsWindowVisible(wnd) // невидимые
and (GetWindow(wnd, gw_owner) = 0) //дочерние
and (GetWindowText(wnd, buff, SizeOf(buff)) <> 0) then
begin
end;
wnd := GetWindow(wnd, gw_hwndnext);
begin
h:=findwindow('Notepad',nil);
if h<>0 then
SendMessage(h,wm_gettext,200,Integer(@buf));
Caption:=buf;
```

То ищет по заголовкв окна, то ещё по фигне какой-то... Если в окне есть кнопка с определенным текстом или Textbox, нужно проверить, тот ли текст, и вывести, например, msg. Код не полный, по количеству символов нельзя отправить.

Comment: @i368, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: У вас в коде каша какая-то. Для чего в вашем коде вот такая конструкция:

    if ... then
    begin
    end;
?

Comment: @i368, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

С помощью [EnumChildWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), перебирайте там компоненты окна, пытайтесь получить [GetWindowText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) и сравнивайте с нужным.